# Options to improve clarity and reduce sediment in a barrel conditioned lager

Tags: secondary-fermentation, sediment

My home-brew lager that I start secondary fermentation (in May) still hasn't settled, we have had spells of warm weather, and my beer still isn't clear... it has been further delayed as I had to vent the gas due to high pressure causing  leak, so this had made sediment rise again. It's been 1mnth untouched and still isn't clear enough... is there anything I can do to speed the process ?

I.E. if I moved it outside, would that cause too much movement and rise the sediment, or do you think I would be safe? we have a cool few days coming with cold winds.

Comment: Lager, you mean?   What do you mean by "had to vent the gas"?   If it's fermenting, the gas should be vented.   Are you intending to bottle or keg this beer?

Comment: Lager, yeah sorry- I had to open the top, an then re-add gas.  Intend to leave it in it's barrel / keg

Comment: So, you're fermenting in a keg, and you're going to serve out of the same keg?

Comment: primary was in a barrel, then I syphoned it into a barrel for secondary fermentation, where it is now

Answer (score 2):

When you serve from the keg, the first couple of pints will be cloudy, even if the rest of the beer is clear, so you need to pull a couple of pints before you can judge cloudiness.

There are a couple of ways to speed up sedimentation

- cold crash - chill the beer to 33F for a week or longer
- use gelatin finings - again, chill the beer to 33F or as cold as you can get it dissolve the gelatin in 170F water, let it cool, and add to the beer. Let it settle for 48 hours. Pour off the first couple of pints and the rest will run clear.

If this is a true lager then you should let it sit at around 33F-39F for at least a month. This will improve the flavor considerably. If the lager is a lager-style beer kit, then gelatin is probably the quickest way, while cold crashing the least obtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Add Irish moss on the last 15 min of boil next time. I also use a 2 stage (10 and 5 micron) filter system right off the keg line up to my tap. That's the only way to get truly clear beer at home